# How to get the list elements at each index separately using java

Tags: java, list

How to Print the list elements separately using Java
.i.e., I have a list of elements with different calculatedvalue and different updatevalues. I want to display `calvalue1` and `updateval1` separately into two different variables say `calvalue1` into `double calValue` and `updateval1` into `double updateValue`.And the loop should iterate until list becomes empty.Can anyone provide me the logic please help me.

list has at 1st line 0.98 and 23/12/2005 (list.get(0))
   at 2nd line 2.3 and 08/09/2013 (list.get(1))
   and so on

```
//here WebAvail is my class

List<WebAvail> list= new List<WebAvail>();
String query="select calvalue,updateval from sample where url='www.abc.com';
list=session.createQuery(query).list;
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{
  for(int j=0;j<list.get(i);j++)
  {
     list.get(j);
  }
}
```

i.e., `list.get(0)` gives me 1st line of the list.In that line I am having `calvalue1` and `updateval1` say 0.98 and 23/12/2005.I need those values seperately i.e., 0.98 into one variable and 23/12/2005 into another variable(that is I want to access seperately).`list.get(0).get(0)` is not valid.
How can I get that one.And also If I do like in the above code snippet  It is giving me                                `"ClassCastException:unable to cast java.lang.object to java.util.list".`Here I am not having problem with query and execution of query.I checked the list by forwarding it to jsp.And jsp displaying list values.But I want list elements in `WebAvail` separately as I mentioned above.

Comment: Please show us more code. For example the declaration of list, what goes in there and what are calvalue and updateval.

Comment: How is `list` defined, and how do you populate it?

Comment: Please see the edited code.And list I have shown you is sample.I don't know whether list elements at each line are seperated by ,(comma).I just kept , to show you list has two elements

Comment: WebAvail is my hibernate generated POJO class.

Comment: @user2365917 `WebAvail is my hibernate generated POJO class` - so it has `getCalvalue()` and `getUpdateval()` methods?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{

  String a[] = list.get(j).toString().split(",");
  Double a1 = Double.parseDouble(a[0].toString());
  String a2 = a[1].toString();

 }
```

Comment: sorry.Please see edited post.How Do I know that list has stored elements by seperating using ,(commas).Please See my edited post.I just kept they are seperated like that

Comment: it is arraylist of arraylist so they are comma separated

Comment: Does the list elements are seperated by , or ; In the above example of list at 1st line 0.98 and 23/12/2005 are seperated by , or ; in the List object??

Answer (score 0):

Is your list.get(0) also returning the list? In this case, you can do the following:

```
double calValue;
Date updateval1;
List listEle = null;
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
 listEle = (List) list.get(i);
 if(null != listEle){
    if(listEle .get(0) instanceof Double)
        calValue = (Double) listEle .get(0);
    if(listEle .get(1) instanceof Date)                 
           updateval1 = (Date) listEle .get(1);
            }
}
```

Comment: Which l1 are you talking about?